# How to filter and append arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have a code that I am using to try and filter out arrays that are missing values as seen here:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

data = '/home/myname/data.fits'
data = Table.read(data, format="fits") 

ID = np.array(data['id'])
ID.astype(str)

redshift = np.array(data['z'])
redshift.astype(float)

radius = np.array(data['r']) 
radius.astype(float)

mag = np.array(data['M'])
mag.astype(float)

def stack(array1, array2, array3, array4):
    #stacks multiple arrays to have corresponding values next to eachother
    stacked_array = [(array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i]) for i in range(0, array1.size)]
    stacked_array = np.array(stacked_array)
    return(stacked_array) 

stacked = stack(ID, redshift, radius, mag)

filtered_array = np.array([])

for i in stacked:
    if not i.any == 'nan':
        np.insert(filtered_array, i[0], axis=0)
```

The last for loop is where i'm having difficulty. I want to insert the rows from my stacked array into my filtered array if it has all of the information (some rows are missing redshift, others are missing magnitude etc...). How would I be able to loop over my stacked array and filter out all of the rows that have all 4 values I want? I keep getting this error currently.

```
TypeError: _insert_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

Comment: There are three required arguments to the np.insert() function, you're giving two, and an optional one (the axis) -- see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Comment: If that doesn't help, can you provide a sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Your `astype` lines aren't doing anything.  Get in the habit of reading function and method docs.  Pay attention to what they return or change. Same applies to your use of `insert`

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],[1,"nan",2,3]]
b=[i for i in a if not any(j=='nan' for j in i)]
```

which prints `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch:

```
for i in stacked:
    if not i.any == 'nan':
        np.insert(filtered_array, i[0], axis=0)
```

to:

```
def any_is_nan(col):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x=='nan',col))) > 0

filtered_array = list(filter(lambda x: not any_is_nan(x),stacked))
```

Please refer to [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).